# How to "black list" pages with a query string parameter

Tags: javascript, cookieconsent

I am using cookieconsent.js to show a popup for users to accept for my website. I need to stop the cookie consent popup from showing if a page has a certain query string.

The [documentation for cookieconsent](https://cookieconsent.osano.com/documentation/javascript-api/) provides a solution to "blacklistPage" where I can "Specify pages using string or RegExp" that I want to prevent the popup from showing on.

This is fine until I try to use regex for a query string.

Example of path, filename and query string to match:
/sub-folder/file-name.shtml?value=pair

```
"blacklistPage": [
    "/.*\?value=pair"
]
```

Comment: What's not fine? I.e. what error are you seeing? I can see that the regex is wrong because the first . forward slash has not been escaped, use https://regexr.com/ to test regex

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alexander. The 'error' is, I'm still seeing the cookie popup. I used https://regex101.com/ to test. There is a greyed out forward slash at the beginning of the field so I put that in too. If I take that out (".*\?value=pair"), I still see the cookie popup though.

Comment: Does the answer given solve your issue?

Comment: Sadly not. I'll comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it's expecting either regex or a string but you're trying to pass regex in a string which isn't valid.

```
using a string : ‘/index.html’ (matches ‘/index.html’ exactly)
using RegExp : /\/page_[\d]+.html/ (matched ‘/page_1.html’ and ‘/page_2.html’ etc)
```

Additionally you're quoting the blacklistPage, this doesn't need to be quoted.

By removing the quotes and provide a standard JS regex format you can make the following:

```
blacklistPage: [
    /\/.*\?value=pair/
]
```

Alternatively your use case is simple so you could just use a string and avoid regex:

```
blacklistPage: [
    '/sub-folder/file-name.shtml?value=pair'
]
```

Comment: OK, I think I understand.

Don't need quotes around blacklistPage. 
The quotes for the value in the array, turned it into a string.
The forward slashes at either end denote regex.
I've now retried `/\/.*\?value=pair/` and `/.*\?value=pair/` but neither work.

For this page, yes, I can just use the string '/sub-folder/file-name.shtml' but there will be other files in different locations which is why I was trying to append the query string. And if it helps, '/sub-folder/file-name.shtml?value=pair' doesn't work, but '/sub-folder/file-name.shtml' (without the query string does.)

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion, along with a friend who knows js much better than I, that the cookieconsent.js script will not allow query strings.